# ID changed to NULL on update - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, model-view-controller, null

I have a landlord and landlord_address model. When a new landlord_address is created, the landlord_id is saved to the table. For some reason, when I edit a landlord_address the landlord_id is changed to NULL.

Models:

```
class Landlord < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :landlord_addresses, dependent: :destroy
   belongs_to :listing_agent, class_name: 'Agent'
end

class LandlordAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :landlord
   has_many :landlord_companies, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Landlord Addresses Controller:

```
module Matrix
   class LandlordAddressesController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_landlord_address, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# GET /landlord_addresses
# GET /landlord_addresses.json
def index
  @landlord = Landlord.find(params[:landlord_id])
  @landlord_addresses = @landlord.landlord_addresses.order(address_line_one: :asc)
end

# GET /landlord_addresses/1
# GET /landlord_addresses/1.json
def show
end

# GET /landlord_addresses/new
def new
  @landlord_address = LandlordAddress.new
  @landlord = Landlord.find(params[:landlord_id])
end

# GET /landlord_addresses/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /landlord_addresses
# POST /landlord_addresses.json
def create
  @landlord_address = LandlordAddress.new(landlord_address_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @landlord_address.save
      format.html { redirect_to matrix_landlord_landlord_addresses_path, notice: 'Landlord address was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @landlord_address }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @landlord_address.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# PATCH/PUT /landlord_addresses/1
# PATCH/PUT /landlord_addresses/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @landlord_address.update(landlord_address_params)
      format.html { redirect_to matrix_landlord_landlord_addresses_path, notice: 'Landlord address was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @landlord_address }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @landlord_address.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# DELETE /landlord_addresses/1
# DELETE /landlord_addresses/1.json
def destroy
  @landlord_address.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to landlord_addresses_url, notice: 'Landlord address was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_landlord_address
    @landlord_address = LandlordAddress.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def landlord_address_params
    params.require(:landlord_address).permit(:address_line_one, :address_line_two, :city, :state, :zip, :super_name, :super_number, :landlord_id, :latitude, :longitude)
  end
 end
end
```

Landlord Addresses _form:

```
<div class="feedback-container">
   <%= form_for [:matrix, @landlord_address] do |f| %>
   <% if @landlord_address.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
         <h2><%= pluralize(@landlord_address.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this landlord_address from being saved:</h2>

         <ul>
            <% @landlord_address.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
               <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
         /ul>
      </div>
   <% end %>

   <div id="form-map"></div>
      <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text"
      placeholder="Enter a location">
   <div id="type-selector" class="controls">
      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-all" checked="checked">
      <label for="changetype-all">All</label>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :address, class: "general-text-label" %>
      <%= f.text_field :address_line_one, class: "general-text-field map-autocomplete-address" %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :latitude, class: "map-autocomplete-latitude" %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :longitude, class: "map-autocomplete-longitude" %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :super_name, class: "general-text-label" %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :super_name, class: "general-text-field" %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :super_number, class: "general-text-label" %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :super_number, class: "general-text-field" %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
      <%= f.hidden_field :landlord_id, :value => params[:landlord_id] %>
   </div><br>
   <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-black btn-4x" %>
   </div>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

Routes:

```
namespace :matrix do    
   resources :landlords, shallow: true do
      resources :landlord_addresses do
         resources :landlord_companies
      end
   end
end
```

New Error:

[image]

Comment: test that what i posted, let me know

Comment: i notice, there no params[:landlord_id] try this one it should work. 
`format.html { redirect_to "/matrix/landlords/#{@landlord_address.landlord_id}/landlord_addresses", notice: 'Landlord address was successfully updated.' }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route is nested, You dnt need to assign in hidden field. You can do it in the controller, passing params.

**Form:**

Remove hidden field, we are assigning it in the controller!

```
   <div class="field">
      <%= f.hidden_field :landlord_id, :value => params[:landlord_id] %>
   </div><br>
```

**Controller:**

```
# POST /landlord_addresses
# POST /landlord_addresses.json
def create
  @landlord_address = LandlordAddress.new(landlord_address_params)

  # add this line here!
  @landlord_address.landlord_id = params[:landlord_id]

  respond_to do |format|
    if @landlord_address.save
      format.html { redirect_to matrix_landlord_landlord_addresses_path, notice: 'Landlord address was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @landlord_address }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @landlord_address.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end


private

#ALSO REMOVE `:landlord_id` from 
def landlord_address_params
    params.require(:landlord_address).permit(:address_line_one, :address_line_two, :city, :state, :zip, :super_name, :super_number, :latitude, :longitude)
end
```

Comment: That is not working. The ID is still being changed to NULL on update. Any idea why?

Comment: sorry my bad probably should be `params[:landlord_id]`, updated post. also, dnt update it, create new landlord_address.

Comment: I changed it and it is still changing to NULL. I added the error above and it looks like the landlord_id is not being passed.

Comment: That works, now I am just having an issue with the redirect, but the ID persists! Thank you.

Comment: @MikeWiesenhart, its just missing the `landlord_id` in DB. all you need is assign one time when creating and its all enough. Dnt forget to update controller, check my post again to remove `:landlord_id` from `.permit`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124670/discussion-between-mike-wiesenhart-and-7urkm3n).

Answer (score 2):

This part

```
 <%= f.hidden_field :landlord_id, :value => params[:landlord_id] %>
```

will be your issue. When `params[:landlord_id]` is `nil` your record will be updated to `null`.

You should change it to

```
 <%= f.hidden_field :landlord_id, :value => @landlord_address.landlord_id || @landlord.id %>
```

or some thing else.

Comment: That didn't work. The ID is saving initially, but is still changing to NULL after update.

Comment: Check `landlord_address_params` within your logfile or via debugger. I think for some reasons `landlord_id` is nil.

Comment: I added the error above and it looks like the landlord_id is not being passed.